# Is it possible to use only right turns using Google Maps Api Direction Services?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have implemented a distance & direction calculator system using Google Maps API.
Below is the demo of it.

http://aslamdoctor.com/demo/distance_calculator/

I want to make a change in it so that the route it generate should only use RIGHT turns only and not the left turns.

Is it Possible? If so, is there any reference I can use?